# Как в resource.rc на основе языка системы выводить разные строки

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, resources

Гуглил, но про то как в этом файле сделать многоязычность ничего не нашёл, везде сложно всё, связанное с какими-то stringtable.

Как мне добавить русский перевод для этих данных, чтобы в английской системе показались английские свойства, а на русской - русские?

```
#include <windows.h>

// The applications main icon
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "icon.ico"

1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 0,1,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 0,1,0,0
FILETYPE VFT_APP
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "100904E4"
        {
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Author"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "0.1"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Program"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Text editor"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "© 2019"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks", ""
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "texteditor.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Text editor"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "0.1"
        }
    }

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x1009, 1252
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя директиву [LANGUAGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/language-statement) можно задавать язык описанных далее ресурсов. После компиляции в исполняемый файл загрузчик ресурсов автоматически будет выбирать наиболее подходящий в соответствии со списком предпочитаемых языков пользователя.

```
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

// нейтральные ресурсы...
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "icon.ico"

LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

// русские ресурсы...
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
...

LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

// английские ресурсы...
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
...
```

Comment: Можете показать пример на моём файле? А то я не понимаю куда и как это прописывать. Там блоки у меня, и нет никакого VS_VERSION_INFO, только блок "StringFileInfo" и "VarFileInfo". Только полный пример, а не обрывками, я так не пойму, полный готовый файл

Comment: @Debugger55 Как же нет? У вас идут блоки `1 VERSIONINFO`

Comment: А, не заметил. И как это прописывать? Покажите полный пример на моём файле, выдаёт ошибки синтаксиса почему-то. И там не VS_VERSION_INFO а просто 1 VERSIONINFO. С какой версии windows поддерживаются эти атрибуты языка?

Comment: @Debugger55 Ну просто место `VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO` вставляете весь блок `1 VERSIONINFO`. Синтаксис ресурсных файлов явно не менялся очень давно. А если есть ошибки синтаксиса - то извольте задавать новый вопрос с их описанием и примером кода для их воспроизведения.

Comment: Так что ли нужно?
https://pastebin.com/RN4sYBkj

Comment: @Debugger55 Похоже на то.

Comment: Спасибо, работает но у меня почему-то отображаются только числа, а слова исчезли. Как правильно внести русский язык в эту строку? ID я нашёл на сайте microsoft, а какую кодировку брать я не знаю VALUE "Translation", 0x0419, 1252

Comment: @Debugger55 Кодировку можно найти на msdn https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/varfileinfo-block По идее, имеет смысл испльзовать только 1200, то бишь юникод

Comment: не помогло.....

Comment: А файл сам в юникод кодировке? И приложение?

Comment: файл windows-1252. у меня даже английские символы пропадают, стоит поставить 0x0419. ни 1200 ни 1251 не помогли

Comment: Ну вот. Сохраняйте файл в юникод кодировке, то бишь UTF16. 1252 1251 вообще нигде не стоит использовать

Comment: У меня нет в notepad++ unicode, только utf-8, а на той странице в списке его нет

Comment: @Debugger55 У меня в notepad++ Unicode есть, только там он называется UCS2

Comment: UCS-2 BE BOM поставил, тоже самое, весь текст пропадает, вместо названия программы пишет Приложение, и все поля кроме версии пустые, даже если они на английском

Comment: Почему BE? Обычно же наоборот, а Bom компилятор ресурсов вроде раньше не переваривал

Comment: Ни LE ни BE не помогли

Comment: Я понял в чём проблема, забыл в блоке поменять 100904E4

Comment: Вообщем, получилось сделать перевод только так: файл конвертировал в windows-1251, в русском поставил BLOCK "041904E4" и VALUE "Translation", 0x0419, 0x04E4, а в английском BLOCK "100904E4" и VALUE "Translation", 0x1009, 0x04E4. После этого символы все отображаются нормально и нигде не пропадают. Unicode это плохой вариант, поддерживается не везде, в том же wine у меня в нём русские символы не отображались правильно